# How to solve the problem that Chrome doesn't obey "Show Window side by side" on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

If I bring out Firefox and Chrome, and right click on the task bar and choose "Show Windows side by side", Chrome will not be arranged side by side.

But if it is Firefox and Internet Explorer, then the 2 Windows will in fact be arranged side by side.

If it is Chrome showing and we press and hold "Window key" and LEFT ARROW, then in fact it does move to the left as a half size window.  So Chrome partially work on Windows 7 for the expected behavior.

Any method to make it work for the first case?   .

Comment: File a bug report, maybe? That might take a while, but it would be reported then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely the same underlying issue as [bug 900](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=900) for Chromium. There may be nothing to do until that bug is fixed.

Comment: that is a bizarre problem